# No social login in jhipster with separated frontend and backend

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying JHipster with separated frontend and backend. I've generated the backend with `yo` `jhipster:server` and the following configurations:

```
? (1/16) What is the base name of your application? myapp
? (2/16) What is your default Java package name? com.package
? (3/16) Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale your application? No
? (4/16) Which *type* of authentication would you like to use? JWT authentication (stateless, with a token)
? (5/16) Which *type* of database would you like to use? SQL (H2, MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MSSQL)
? (6/16) Which *production* database would you like to use? Microsoft SQL Server
? (7/16) Which *development* database would you like to use? H2 with disk-based persistence
? (8/16) Do you want to use Hibernate 2nd level cache? Yes, with ehcache (local cache, for a single node)
? (9/16) Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Maven
? (10/16) Which other technologies would you like to use? Social login (Google, Facebook, Twitter), API first development using swagger-codegen
? (11/16) Would you like to enable internationalization support? Yes
? Please choose the native language of the application Portuguese (Brazilian)
? Please choose additional languages to install English
```

Since I selected the social login option when generating the application, the dependencies for google and facebook login are in my `pom.xml` and I already added the `client-id` and `client-secret` to `application.yml`.

I get to login with the precreated users: admin and user. But the social login is missing.
Perhaps it's relevant to say that when I create an application without separating backend from frontend (just by running jhipster), social login works just fine.